# Unexpected token on bash file backtrack5 r2

Tags: bash, login, backtrack

When I log in, appears the following error:

`-bash: /etc/profile: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token ('`

Inside the file there is the next code:

`n# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))\n`

`# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).\n\nif`

`[ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then\nfor i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do\nif [ -r $i ];`

`then\n. $i\nfi\ndone\nunset i\nfi\n\nif [ "$PS1" ]; then\nif [ "$BASH" ];`

`then\nPS1=u@h:w$ \nif [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ];`

`then\n.`

`/etc/bash.bashrc\nfi\nelse\nif [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ];`

`then\nPS1=# \nelse\nPS1=$ \nfi\nfi\nfi\n\numask`

`022\nPT5HOME=/opt/pt\nexport PT5HOME`

I've searched around on internet but I didn't find something understandable or that matches with my problem (I think), how could fix this, it seems not to trouble anything with the computer, but I'd like to know what it's going on.

Comment: @jw013 that is the way the code is inside the file...

Comment: @jw013 Hope it's ok now

Comment: If that is true, then that is the reason for the error - `bash` doesn't know what to do with the very garbled formatting.  I'd recommend just retyping it.  Where did you get this horrendous `profile`?  Did Backtrack really ship with this?

Comment: @jw013 yep, I did not mess up with the file, I reformat a little the code just to see it better, how can I correct it??

Comment: Replace all the `\n` with actual newlines and delete the very first `n`.

Comment: how can I do this safely, I mean, if I screw it up, how could I roll back the changes?

Comment: For something this simple, you could just use a text editor, or just replace the entire file with what @Renan has already done for you.

Comment: @poz2k4444: you can always make a copy of a file before editing it - e.g. `cp /etc/profile /etc/profile.bak`.  If you mess up the edit, just copy the .bak file back in to place.  BTW, you can also use the backup file to get a diff of what changed, e.g. `diff -u /etc/profile.bak /etc/profile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the formatting, replace the `\n` by actual newlines and remove the spurious 'n' at the beginning, then it works. Thus:

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r "$i" ]; then
      . "$i"
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi

if [ -n "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ -n "$BASH" ]; then
    PS1='u@h:w$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi
umask 022
PT5HOME=/opt/pt
export PT5HOME
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly, why bash doesn't support `\n` or why I have to reformat the code?